# Erase children of an InkCanvas

Tags: c#, wpf, inkcanvas

I have an `InkCanvas` on a window in which I allow the user to draw with a stylus, touch, or mouse. I also allow the user to add text. The user taps an "add text" button, then taps where on the canvas they would like their text. A textbox appears there, allowing them to type. On enter or lost focus I create a `ContentControl` and add it to `myInkCanvas.Children`.

I would like the user to be able to erase the text they have created when the `InkCanvas` is in erase mode (I am using `EraseByPoint`). I've attempted to capture the `MouseEnter` and `PreviewMouseMove` events of the content controls, but neither seem to fire.

Is there an event that I can capture? Is there a better way to handle this scenario? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use hit testing for this purpose 
look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx)

get InkPresenter first

```
public T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
{
    T child = default(T);
    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
        Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        child = v as T;
        if (child == null)
        {
            child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
        }
        if (child != null)
            break;
    }
    return child;
}

InkPresenter inkPresenter = GetVisualChild<InkPresenter>(myInkCanvas);
```

then get HitTestResult of your Point

```
HitTestResult hitTestResult = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(inkPresenter, new Point(x, y));
```

then you can use `hitTestResult.VisualHit` to remove this object

Comment: So, I would need to capture a mouse event on the inkcanvas and on each event perform the hit test on each child of the inkcanvas?

Comment: Looks cool. I can't seem to find a generic version of GetVisualChild. What namespace is that in?

Comment: Not a problem. I ended up creating one that was similar (but not as good) as your's.

Comment: Everything is working with the hit testing. I'm making an EllipseGeometry that matches the size/shape of the eraser cursor for the hit parameter. In the HitTestResultCallback I'm using `myInkCanvas.Children.Remove((UIElement)result.VisualHit);` but the child element isn't being removed from the inkcanvas. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes sure you can use [GeometryHitTestParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometryhittestparameters.aspx)